# GLUT animation leads to 100% utilization of 1 core when the window is invisible

Tags: glut, pyopengl

I developed a Python program that uses PyOpenGL and GLUT for window management to show an animation. In order to have the animation run at the fastest possible framerate, I set

```
glutIdleFunc(glutPostRedisplay)
```

as recommended e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19069635/2056067).

That works well, I get a steady 60 FPS with not a lot of CPU load.

However, as soon as the window is hidden by another window, one CPU core jumps to 100% utilization.

My suspicion is that while the window is visible, the rate at which the `glutDisplayFunc` is called is limited, because it contains a call `glutSwapBuffers()` which waits for vsync; and that this limitation fails when it is invisible.

I tried to solve the problem by keeping track of visibility (through a `glutVisibilityFunc`) and putting the following code at the beginning of my `glutDisplayFunc`:

```
if not visible:
    time.sleep(0.1)
    return
```

This does not however have the desired effect.

What's happening here, and how do I avoid it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution [here](http://www.dei.isep.ipp.pt/~matos/cg/docs/manual/glutIdleFunc.3GLUT.html),
and it is obvious once you know it: Disable the `glutPostRedisplay` as `glutIdleFunc` when the window becomes invisible. Concretely, use a `glutVisibilityFunc` like this:

```
def visibility(state):
    if state == GLUT_VISIBLE:
        glutIdleFunc(glutPostRedisplay)
    else:
        glutIdleFunc(None)
```